# Is ext js compatible with .jsp, java backend?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, extjs

Is ext js compatible with .jsp, java backend?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ext JS is a javascript library. It exists at the client side of the browser. So it doesn't matter whether you use PHP, JSP or ASP.Net, as long as a browser supports javascript, ExtJS will work there.

Answer (score 3):

In short, yes, but see the following article, in terms for ease of use integration (tag library) wise:

http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/ext_js_tag_library

and the referenced article:

http://blog.james-carr.org/2008/01/22/making-extjs-more-accessible-to-java-developers/

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend taking a look at Grails. It lives in the java world, and plays extremely nice together with ExtJS. For example, you probably will have to generate and parse a lot of JSON between server and ExtJS client, and Grails does that as if it was a language built-in.